# Diferencia en creación de objetos c#

Tags: c#

Cuál es la diferencia entre hacer esto:

```
Recibo recibo = new Recibo();
```

En donde `Recibo` es una clase, Y esto:

```
Impuestos impuestos;
```

En donde `Impuestos` también es una clase.

Answer (score 5):

En la primera estas declarando una variable de tipo `Recibo` y además la estás instanciando con un nuevo objeto de tipo `Recibo`.

En el segundo caso solo estás declarando la variable de tipo `Impuestos` y al no instanciarla tendrá el valor por defecto que en el caso de los reference types es `null`.

Ten en cuenta que en el primer caso también pudiste haberlo definido de esta manera:

```
var recibo = new Recibo();
```

El resultado es exactamente el mismo: Se define una varible de tipo `Recibo` y se la instancia con un objeto de tipo `Recibo` ya que C# infiere el tipo de la variable con el tipo del valor de retorno de la expresión de la derecha de la asignación es decir `new Recibo()`.

En el segundo caso ya que no se asigna nada es obligatorio indicar el tipo de la variable

Comment: Excelente explicación, gracias.

Comment: @tacvborocker no te olvides de aceptar la respuesta que correspondas correcta.

Answer (score 3):

```
Impuestos impuestos;
```

En C# en este caso no estas creando un objeto o instancia de Impuesto, sino solo la referencia a el, por lo tanto la variable impuestos tendrá valor null.

```
Recibo recibo = new Recibo();
```

En este caso, estas creando una instancia de Recibo y estas guardando su referencia en la variable "recibo".

Answer (score 1):

Cuando escribes `Recibo recibo = new Recibo();` creas una nueva instancia de la clase `Recibo`. Las instancias son objetos que se crean y almacenan en memoria. A ellos puedes acceder despues de inicializados junto con todas sus operaciones de ahí que se utilize `new` antes de la clase. Puedes inicializar una clase `Object objeto = new Recibo()` también.

La segunda linea `Impuestos impuestos;` solo declara la variable `impuestos` pero todavía no tiene guardada la instancia de `Impuestos`. De manera que si la llamas te retornara un valor nulo.

Normalmente al principio de tu código declaras las variables que quieres utilizar y despues la inicializas (Cuando quieres variables globales) pero si quieres trabajar de manera local lo haces todo en una sola línea.

Comment: En C# **todo** hereda de `object`

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Gracias por el dato.

Answer (score 1):

Paso a aclarar un error de concepto.

Tanto:

```
Recibo recibo ...
```

Como:

```
Impuestos impuestos;
```

Son solamente declaraciones de variables del tipo Recibo e Impuestos respectivamente. Estas variables, para ser utilizadas, deberán primero apuntar a un objeto en memoria.

No es hasta que haces **new** de la clase que creas una nueva instancia de que puedes usar:

```
   Recibo recibo; // Aqui declaramos la variable recibo. La misma es sólo el punto de acceso a una futura instancia. Todavía no hay objeto en memoria asignado a la misma. 

   recibo = new Recibo(); // Aqui es cuando, mediante la palabra reservada *new*, creamos el objeto en memoria. A partir de este momento es que pueden ser usados sus métodos y propiedades.
```

Espero haber aclarado tu duda. Saludos!